# Finding by Keyword part of string, select all cells (whole rows), copy the range to another sheet and print it

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I'm new to `VBA` and have already found few similar questions previously answered here, both similar but also quite different as I'd like to make the search comfortable for people not experienced with excel or the relatively long product catalogue (~1500 different products) the company I work for offers.

The workbook has 3 sheets, where Sheet 1 contains only a greeting incl. a description of the search function. I inserted a text box (active x) which is linked to a cell (in my case D24) and a search button (command button) called "Search". In Sheet 3 I have the list of products in columns B:E called "product_category", "sub_category", "product_number", "Product_name" and "product_specification" (column A is called "Sequent_Number" and is not relevant in this case).

In Sheet 2 I have a title row with all column headers from Sheet3 and I use it to paste results (cleaning first 200 rows as in some categories there are slightly over 100 products) and print.

There are 2 problems to solve:

- How I can I, expand the search range to all columns,
- How I can search in part of the string (not only exact match) as current.

The current code is:

```
Sub Search_ProductName_by_Keyword()
Dim ProductName As String
Dim Finalrow As String
Dim i As Integer
ProductName= Sheet1.Range("D24").Value
Sheet2.Range("B6: E200").ClearContents
Sheet3.Select
Finalrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To finalrow
If Cells(i, 5) = ProductName Then
Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 7)).Copy
Sheet2.Select
Range("B200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet3.Select
End If
Next i
Sheet1.Select
Range("d24").Select
End Sub
```

I'm open for any ideas or suggestions. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) your cells(I,5) is fixed to column E, look at `Find` or `MATCH` on Erow:Xrow, 2) look a `Instr` or `Like`

Comment: thinking on it, for both use FIND on xlPart

Comment: Hi Natahan_Sav, Actually I tried that just few min. ago and stacked due to a syntax problem, but I guess that's the right way to make it work, so I'll persist on that method.
Thanks!

Comment: if not Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 7)).find(x,y,z) is nothing then

Comment: OK here is what I typed in my existing code:

"For i = 2 To finalrow

If Not Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 7)).Find(What:=ProductName, After:=Range("B2"), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing Then

Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 7)).Copy
Range("B200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet3.Select

End If

Next i
"
And I receive error "Type mismatch".

Comment: `.Find(What:="def", After:=Range("B" & i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=   False, SearchFormat:=False)`

Comment: still type mismatch... could it be from the version of excel (2007)? It is not the first time I try code working on previous or latest versions and it is not working. Anyway I'll try with calling auto filter to see if it will work that way.

Comment: You need to set it to a range, then check the range,`Set r = Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 10)).Find(What:="def", After:=Range("E" & i), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
`  see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to use [AutoFilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx):

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim ProductName As String

    ProductName = Sheet1.Range("D24").Value
    Sheet2.Range("B5: E200").ClearContents '<--| clear headers too, since they will be readded from AutoFilter selected cells

    With Sheet3
        With .Range("E1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns E cells from row 1 down to last not empty cell
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & ProductName & "*"  '<--| filter it on its 1st (and only) column with "*'ProductName'* values
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any filtered cells other than headers
                Intersect(.Parent.Range("B:E"), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow).Copy '<-- copy filtered cells, headers included
                Sheet2.Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '<--| paste values only from Sheet2 cell "B5"
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove AutoFilter and show all rows back
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks user3598756! This works fine, only for column E, but I'll find a way to extend the range to columns from B to E.

Comment: @MilenK., BTW the code already acts on a range extending from B to E

Comment: I did! and also I'm curious to see this code, nevertheless I made mine in a way that suits me well already :) Thanks again!

Comment: I tested the last one, works fine. Thanks again user3598756!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

Dim r As Range
Dim strProductName As String

strProductName = "DEF"

For i = 2 To 10

Set r = Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 10)).Find(What:=strProductName, After:=Cells(i, 5), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not r Is Nothing Then Debug.Print i

Next i

End Sub
```

You'll need to change the search range

Comment: Hi Nathan_Sav, I accepted your last solution as it worked (on another version of excel (my colleague's PC). Unfortunately the type of data led to messy sellections caused by find by xlPart (like part/substring of product names matching product numbers containing similar pice of text. In my case I used instead of one search button 4 dedicated to each criteria and searching by autofilter (the solution provided by user_3598756) by column. Thank you for your help anyway!